# Check type of an input field with php

Tags: php, types, input

I would like to check the type of an input field text is. Cause i only want to make thos fields read only. I know i can do this in javascript, but is there any way that this is possible in php?

best regrads.

Comment: why is "checking type" related to "read only"? i can't get the point

Comment: cause i got a huge form with all kinde of elements and i only want to make my text fields read only

Comment: did you mean you wish to know whether a field is read only when you submit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable an input field add disabled attribute:

```
 disabled="disabled"
```

This has to be done when generating the html or with javascript after generation.

This is a clean way of doing it and the user sees directly that it is just readable but not editable.

When you submit a form, in php you take the name attribute to get the posted value. Say you have

```
<input name="address" type="text">
```

In php:

```
if($_POST['address']){
   //don't process address cause you know this is of type text
}
```

Answer (score 1):

same as javascript use this

```
 <input name="address" type="text" readonly="readonly">
```

this make field read only you can't change it.

```
 <input name="address" type="text" value="<?php echo "your value"; ?>" readonly="readonly">
```

try this code

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it in php,if $field is false then set input disabled

```
<input type="text" name="" <?php echo ($field == false)? 'disabled="disabled"' : '';?> value="" />
```